# Add color to JTable rows

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable

I Want change the color of my JTable rows.

When i set a row in JTable,The first row become RED color.And then when i want add new row the first row become yellow and the second row become red;

[image: red JTable row]
[image: yellow red JTable row]

I do not use repaint() Becouse repaint all time work.I want just one time.When i Use repaint or tablemodel.setfile... the table constantly update

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a [custom cell renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer).

A cell renderer is responsible for creating a Component which the cells actually display. (The cell renderer Component is not actually *added* to the JTable. The JTable just uses it to do painting.) `DefaultTableCellRenderer` creates JLabels so you can set their background and foreground colors freely. You don't need to do painting.

[image: one]
[image: two]

You can pretty much display the cells however you want to. I wasn't sure how you wanted it to look after two rows so I guessed.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CustomCellRenderer implements Runnable, ActionListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CustomCellRenderer());
    }

    JTable table;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Custom Cell Renderer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(0, 2) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
                return Object.class;
            }
        });

        class RedYellowRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
            RedYellowRenderer() {
                setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
            }
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column
            ) {
                Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column
                );

                if(row == 0 && table.getRowCount() > 1) {
                    c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                    c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                } else {
                    c.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    c.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                }

                return c;
            }
        }

        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new RedYellowRenderer());
        table.setTableHeader(null);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Add Row");
        btn.addActionListener(this);

        JToolBar bar = new JToolBar();
        bar.setFloatable(false);
        bar.add(btn);

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(bar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        content.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setContentPane(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        int nextRow = table.getRowCount();
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[] { "NAME" + nextRow, "SPORT" + nextRow });
    }
}
```