# Change Color of JTable Row Based on the Value of the Database

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

```
tblApplicant = new javax.swing.JTable(){
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
    {
    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

    //  Alternate row color
    String value = (String) tblApplicant.getValueAt(row, 4);
    if (value == "Single" && !isRowSelected(row))
    c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    return c;
}
```

};

This is my New Codes im trying to get the value of column 4 and equal it to single if its true the background is change.
but this is not working

Comment: Take a look at [How to use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Using Custom Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Comment: I showed an example of a custom renderer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26982799/2891664

Comment: @Radiodef You could use that as a duplicate close option

Comment: @MadProgrammer I suppose. The OP needs to do a bit of thinking to apply it to their own needs though. ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding the `prepareRender(...)` method of the `JTable` allows your to customize rendering for the entire row based on a value in one of the columns.

The basic logic would be something like:

```
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
{
    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

    //  Color row based on a cell value

    if (!isRowSelected(row))
    {
        c.setBackground(getBackground()); // set default background

        int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
        String value = (String)getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, ???);

        if ("Single".equals(value)) c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }

    return c;
}
```

Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for more information and working examples.

Comment: but how can i connect it to the database?
because i want to color the row which is the value is came from the database

Comment: Never ever try to connect to a database in a renderer. The code in a renderer must be extremely fast. If you want to highlight the color of a row based on some data, then the data must be in the TableModel. So when you do your database query you must get the end date and store the data in the TableModel.

Comment: Of what? I don't know SQL. I gave you examples of how to do the rendering on data that is contained in a TableModel.

Comment: i see. right now i know how to change the background of jTable but my problem is what if it is connected to database..
thank you for your help

Comment: Bro what if i want to change the background of row base on the column value?
Can u give me another tutorial or example?